# I need Javascript syntax and logic advice

Tags: javascript, logic

I have a two part question. The first is that I tried to replace all of my document.write with innerHTML and now nothing generates on the page correctly. The second part of my question is that I can't figure out the logic on my toggleCurrent function so that I can hide show the currently displayed view. example - if the thumbnail view is visible I want to hide/show or if the full view is visible I want to hide/show that. http://jsfiddle.net/5M3k7/

```
//Creating generic Object
function Person(name,age,biog,thumb,char,bg,cider) {
    this.fullName = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.biog = biog;
    this.thumb = thumb;
    this.char = char;
    this.bg = bg;
    this.cider = cider;
}


//Creating new Objects
var jay = new Person ("Jay Jones",24,"Story","img","guy","bg","Fleet",true);
var jai = new Person ("Jai Janes",23,"Story","img","gal","bg","Sleet",true);
var dan = new Person ("Dan Dones",19,"Story","img","guy","bg","Leet",true);
var den = new Person ("Den Danes",49,"Story","img","guy","bg","Treat",true);
var dun = new Person ("Dun Dunes",20,"Story","img","guy","bg","Meet",true);
var vim = new Person ("Vim Vanes",22,"Story","img","guy","bg","Meat",true);

//Defining arrays
var characters = [jay, jai, dan, den, dun, vim];

//For loop goes though character array and prints it out.
var thumbs = function() {
    var full = document.getElementById('full');
    var cLength = characters.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < cLength; i++){
    full.innerHTML = '<div class="wrap"><div class="cont">' + "Name: " + characters[i].fullName + '<br/>' + 'Age: ' + characters[i].age + '<br/>' + 'Cider: ' + characters[i].cider + '</div></div>';
    }
    return;
};

var full = function() {
    var thumb = document.getElementById('fullthumb');
    var cLength = characters.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < cLength; i++){
    thumb.innerHTML = '<div class="fullwrap"><div class="bg"><div class="fullcont">Name: '
+ characters[i].fullName + '<br/> Age:' + characters[i].age + '<br/>Cider:' + characters[i].cider + '<div class="char"></div></div></div></div>';
    }
    return;
};

//Toggle Function
function toggleMenuDiv() {
var full = document.getElementById('full');
var thumb = document.getElementById('fullthumb');
var butt = document.getElementById('button');
   if (full.style.display == 'none') {
     full.style.display = 'block';
     thumb.style.display = 'none';
     butt.innerHTML = 'THUMB VIEW<span class="arrow-e"></span>';
   }
   else {
     full.style.display = 'none';
     thumb.style.display = 'block';
     butt.innerHTML = 'FULL VIEW<span class="arrow-e"></span>';
   }
}

//Toggle Function
function toggleCurrent() {
var chng = document.getElementById('change');
var thumb = document.getElementById('fullthumb');
var full = document.getElementById('full');
while (full.style.display == 'none')
  {
  if(thumb.style.display == 'block') {
     chng.innerHTML = 'HIDE<span class="arrow-n"></span>';
  }else{
     thumb.style.display = 'none';
     chng.innerHTML = 'SHOW<span class="arrow-s"></span>';
  }
  }

}
```

Comment: is there a reason you are assigning functions to variables ( thumbs, full etc) instead of just doing regular function constructors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you keep overriding the last thing entered in.

```
full.innerHTML = '<div class="wrap"><div class="cont">' + "Name: " + characters[i].fullName + '<br/>' + 'Age: ' + characters[i].age + '<br/>' + 'Cider: ' + characters[i].cider + '</div></div>';
```

You are need to append to the innerHTML

```
full.innerHTML = full.innerHTML + '<div class="...
```

Comment: Oh! I think I see what you mean it keeps adding it to the same spot. How would you write it?

Comment: If I do full.innerHTML = full.innerHTML + '<div class="... and then do full.innerHTML = full.innerHTML + '<div class="... again isn't that still overriding it?

Comment: `var a = 1; a = a + 1; a = a + 1; console.log(a);` In your argument, a  would be 1, not 3. Test it out, see what happens.

Comment: I just looked at my thumb and full functions and the innerhtml is only being used once. Its just not displaying the only other thing that happens to the information above is a style change. I think there is some other reason why its not displaying.

Comment: Well that `while{full.style.display == 'none'}` is in infinite loop

Comment: I got it to a point where its working so I am going to go with it. I have not come across a problem using document.write yet so until I get more confident I think I am going to stick with it